# What is the etymology of "board" as in boarding a ship or an airplane?

Tags: etymology

I'm wondering if it is stemming from using boards as bridges between the land and the vessel?

Comment: You could have looked it up here: [link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=board)

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer: Board refers to the side of the ship, not (just) the plank that can be used to board the ship

> board (n.2) 
>   "side of ship," Old English bord "border, rim, ship's side," from Proto-Germanic *bordaz (source also of Old Saxon bord, Dutch boord "border, edge, ship's side," German Bord "margin, border," Old High German bart, Old Norse barð "margin, shore, ship-board"), perhaps from the same source as board (n.1), but not all sources accept this. Connected to border; see also starboard.
>
> If not etymologically related to board (n.1), the two forms represented in English by these words were nonetheless confused at an early date in most Germanic languages, a situation made worse in English because this Germanic word also was adopted in Medieval Latin as bordus (source of Italian and Spanish bordo) and entered Old French as bort "beam, board, plank; side of a ship" (12c., Modern French bord), via either Medieval Latin or Frankish, and from thence it came over with the Normans to mingle with its native cousins. By now the senses are inextricably tangled. Some etymology dictionaries treat them as having been the same word all along.

From  [online etymology](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=board&allowed_in_frame=0--the)

Board (n.1) is a  flat piece of timber

Edit: I have modified the first sentence

Comment: Some useful information. Nevertheless, I'm having trouble tracing the precise etymology to the verb "to board": are we sure that it refers to the (vertical) side of the ship? Is it confirmed somewhere that it's not the deck or some other plank-like part, like the gangplank? The word "on" as in "on board" is slightly puzzling without intermediate etymological steps, if it comes from board "side of a ship".

Comment: @Cerberus That the *sides* of the hull were meant is suggested by many uses: ME spoke of *within* and *without (ship)boards* where we now say *on board* and *off board*, we still speak of a man *overboard* and of something falling *by the board*, and seamen speak of ships being *on board each other* and of the *weatherboard*, the side of the ship closest the wind.

Comment: @StoneyB: OK that's interesting information. The only thing that's missing is the semantic steps from vertical board to being "on board" and "boarding" a ship. A little bit of additional explanation in this answer would be nice.

Comment: @Cerberus *OED 1* says “*On board* appears to be a later expansion (cf. *afoot*, *on foot*) of **Aboard**, *a-bord*, and this to have been taken directly from Fr. *à bord*, as in *aller ou monter à bord, être à bord*, short for *au bord du vaisseau*, in which *bord*, ‘ship’s side’, comes contextually to be equal to ‘ship’ itself.”

Comment: Feel free to enter additional information in this or separate answer, @StoneyB

Comment: I think that "By now the senses are inextricably entangled" says it all!

Comment: @StoneyB The really interesting thing is that the word *board* which entered English from one or other of  Scandinavian, Frisian or Middle High German, also entered French, the OED believes, from one of them. Then it was the French *à bord* which gave rise to the English *aboard*. OED records, for its entry on the verb *board* the following etymology: *< board n.: compare French border ; in senses  4  to 9 influenced by French aborder . Compare abord n* See my answer for further elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

[To board](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/board):

> - verb senses derived from various senses of board and board (n.2) (a flat slab of wood or other material for some specific purpose:) ***include "come alongside" (a ship), mid-15c.***

(Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

The term clearly has its origins in the word ***board*** meaning "a plank of wood".

However that noun has a complex etymology, as the OED explains:

> ***Board*** (noun).
>
> Etymology: A word or agglomeration of words of complicated history,
>   representing two originally distinct nouns, already blended
>   in Old English, and subsequently reinforced in Middle English by
>   French uses of one of them, and possibly by Scandinavian uses of one
>   or both. (1) Old English had bord 1 neuter ‘board, plank, shield, ?
>   table’, a Common Germanic strong neuter noun, = Old Frisian and Old
>   Saxon bord  (Middle Dutch bort, -de , Dutch boord  ‘board’, bord 
>   ‘shelf, plate, trencher’), Middle High German and modern German bort 
>   ‘board’, Gothic baurd  in fotubaurd  ‘foot-stool’, Old Norse borð 
>   ‘board, plank, table, maintenance at table’ (Swedish and Danish bord 
>   table) < Germanic *bord-o(m , repr. an Aryan *bhṛdhom , Sanskrit
>   *bṛdham :

As the extract says, the word was reinforced by French uses of one of these Old English, or Middle High German uses of *bord*.

**When it come to the verb *boarding* - as in *boarding a ship* this is related to the adverb *aboard*, with a French etymology in *à bord***.